# Show that function f(z) has bounded roots.

Tags: complex-analysis

> We have function $$ f(z) = 1 + \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{2!z^{2}} +
>  \ldots \frac{1}{n!z^{n}} $$ show that $\forall \epsilon > 0  \quad
>  \exists N \quad \forall   n > N $ $$f(z) = 0 \implies |z| < \epsilon
>  $$

---

My approach: 
$ z = r e^{i\alpha}$

$$  
1 + e^{-\alpha i}/2! + r^{2} e^{-2i\alpha}/3! + \ldots r^{n} e^{-ni\alpha}/n! = 0
$$
So we have 
$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}r^{i}/i! =0  
$ 
and

$ \sum_{i=0}^{n} e^{i\omega}  = 0$

$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}r^{i}/i! \mapsto e^{n} \text{when i} \mapsto \infty 
$

But am not show the next step. 
Maybe my observations is not useful.  Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We suppose the contrary, i.e. suppose there is an $\epsilon > 0$, such that there is an infinite sequence $N_1 < N_2 < \cdots$, such that the function $f_{N_i}(z) = 1 + z^{-1} + \frac{z^{-2}}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{z^{-N_i}}{N_i!}$ has a root $z_{N_i}$ with $|z_{N_i}| \geq \epsilon$.

By considering $w = z^{-1}$, we see that $g_{N_i}(w) = 1 + w + \frac{w^2}{2!} + \cdots +\frac{w^{N_i}}{N_i!}$ has a root $w_{N_i}$ with $|w_{N_i}| \leq \epsilon^{-1}$.

Since the closed ball $\{w\in\mathbb{C}:|w|\leq \epsilon^{-1}\}$ is compact, there is a subsequence of $(w_{N_i})_i$ converging to a point.

This means that there is a sequence $M_1 < M_2 < \cdots$, such that the limit $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}w_{M_i} = w$ exists.

But then it's a simple exercise to show that $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty}g_{M_i}(w_{M_i}) = 1 + w + \frac{w^2}{2!} + \cdots$.

The left hand side is obviously $0$, and the right hand side is $e^w$, a contradiction.

Comment: This doesn't look correct as the opposite of the hypothesis is the existence of $\epsilon$ and of a sequence $N_k \to \infty$ for which there is a root with absolute value bigger than $\epsilon$. It does not imply the existence of such a root for all $N$ large enough

Comment: @Conrad You are right. Thanks. This is easily corrected by taking again a subsequence.

Comment: I agree that it is easily correctable, my point is that it is incorrect as it is

Comment: @Conrad I was busy editting it (:

Comment: We have closed ball without zero @WhatsUp ?

Comment: @Blabla Yes, but it doesn't matter. Closed ball without zero is included in closed ball, so there is still a limit point in the closed ball.

Comment: So closed ball without zero  is compact in closed ball?

Comment: @Blabla No, but we don't need it to be compact. We only need the compactness of the closed ball. There is an infinite sequence in the closed ball, so there is a limit point.

Comment: Yes, but closed ball without zero is not compactness

Comment: Please, read carefully: we have a sequence $(w_i)_i$, with every $w_i$ in the closed ball without zero. Since the closed ball without zero is contained in the closed ball, we see that all $w_i$ are in fact in the closed ball. Since the closed ball is compact, we conclude that there is a limit point in the closed ball.